# Solve $ \int\frac{1}{\sin(x)-\cos(2x)}dx $ ...

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals, substitution, trigonometric-integrals

Weierstrass substitution :
$$\tan(\frac{x}{2})=t$$  $$\sin(x)=(\frac{2t}{1+t^2})$$  $$\cos(x)=(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2})$$ $$dx=(\frac{2\,dt}{1+t^2})$$

Than : $$\cos(2x)=\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)$$

P.s I tried using these substitutions, but I couldn't get so far .
Need a bit help to solve this problem, if it's possible by using these substitutions.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: @Axel [I don't recommend that](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F%28sin%28x%29-cos%282x%29%29).

Comment: @J.G. You're right. I made a sign mistake.

Comment: @Axel Given [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F%28sin+x%2Bcos+2x%29), I assume the sign error was in [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioche%27s_rules).

Comment: @J.G. Exactly, I am impressed. Are those rules known worldwide or is it not often used?

Comment: @Axel I don't know how well-known they are, but I often cite them so the choice of substitution doesn't look magic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\cos2x=2\cos^2x-1=\frac{1-6t^2+t^4}{(1+t^2)^2}$, $\sin x-\cos 2x=\frac{-1+2t+6t^2+2t^3-t^4}{(1+t^2)^2}$, so your integral is$$\int\frac{2(1+t^2)}{-1+2t+6t^2+2t^3-t^4}dt.$$Sincce $-1+2t+6t^2+2t^3-t^4=-(t^2-4t+1)(t+1)^2$ (the repeated root is easily guessed with the rational root theorem), we seek a partial fraction decomposition:$$\begin{align}\frac{-2(1+t^2)}{(t^2-4t+1)(t+1)^2}&=\frac{At+B}{t^2-4t+1}+\frac{Ct+D}{t^2-4t+1},\\-2(1+t^2)&=(At+B)(t+1)^2+(Ct+D)(t^2-4t+1)\\&=(A+C)t^3+(2A+B-4C+D)t^2\\&+(A+2B+C-4D)t+B+D.\end{align}$$Since $A+C=0,\,2A+B-4C+D=-2,\,A+2B+C-4D=0,\,B+D=-2$, the solution is$$\int\frac{-2(1+t^2)dt}{(t^2-4t+1)(t+1)^2}=\int\left(\frac{-4/3}{t^2-4t+1}+\frac{-2/3}{(t+1)^2}\right)dt,$$which you can finish.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer sir @J.G ,I made it to come to this : $$(-1)\int\frac{2(1+t^2)}{(t^2-4t+1)(t+1)^2}dt.$$ now I'm trying to come to a form who respond to this table formula $$\int\frac{dx}{a^2-x^2}=\frac{1}{2a}\ln(|\frac{x+a}{x-a}|)  $$ ,should I ? :)

Comment: @John With $x=t-2,\,a=\sqrt{3}$, yes.

Comment: @John Can you multiply out denominators to get simultaneous equarions from this?$$\frac{-2(t^2+1)}{(t^2-4t+1)(t+1)^2}=\frac{At+B}{t^2-4t+1}+\frac{Ct+D}{(t+1)^2}$$

Comment: @John See edit.

Comment: Completely understandable @J.G but I'm not clear with this, why do we use same denominator to partial fractions $\frac{-2\cdot(1+t^2)}{(t^2-4t+1)\cdot(t+1)^2}=\frac{At+B}{t^2-4t+1}+\frac{Ct+D}{t^2-4t+1}$,shouldn't it be $\frac{-2\cdot(1+t^2)}{(t^2-4t+1)\cdot(t+1)^2}=\frac{At+B}{t^2-4t+1}+\frac{Ct+D}{t^2+2t+1}$

Comment: @John Thanks; fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Hint

$$\sin x-\cos2x=2s^2+s-1=(s+1)(2s-1)$$ where $s=\sin x$

Now use https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html for $$\dfrac1{2s^2+s-1}=\dfrac a{s+1}+\dfrac b{2s-1}$$

Now $1+\sin x=1+\cos(\pi/2-x)=\dfrac2{\sec^2(\pi/4-x/2)}$

For the other integral, use https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution#The_substitution

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$\sin(x)-\cos(2x)=$$
$$\sin(x)-1+2\sin^2(x)=$$
$$(\sin(x)+1)(2\sin(x)-1)$$

and

$$\frac{1}{\sin(x)-\cos(2x)}=$$
$$\frac 13\Bigl(\frac{-1}{\sin(x)+1}+\frac{2}{2\sin(x)-1}\Bigr)$$

Answer (score 1):

It is better to have the half-angle substitution after the partial decomposition and on $t= \frac\pi2 -x $ instead, as seen below

\begin{align}
 \int\frac{1}{\sin x-\cos 2x}dx
 & =-\int \frac{1}{\cos t+2\cos^2t -1}dt\\
& =\int \frac{1}{(1-2\cos t)(1+\cos t )}dt\\
&= \frac13 \int \left(\frac1{1+\cos t}+ \frac1{\frac12- \cos t}\right)dt\\
&= \frac13 \int \left(\frac12\sec^2\frac t2 -\frac{\frac23 \sec^2\frac t2}{\frac13-\tan^2\frac t2}\right)dt\\
&= \frac13 \tan\frac t2 -\frac4{3\sqrt3} \tanh^{-1}(\sqrt3\tan \frac t2)+C
\end{align}